# Node to Netlify.TOML convertion

Tags: angularjs, node.js, netlify, toml

Does Anyone can Help Related to the Issue as I want to convert NodeJS command

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './../frontend/public')));
```

to netlify.toml format ?
Is it possible ? then how ?
Thanks in advance